# How to get clarity image when capture from camera?

Tags: java, android

capture image from `camera` then convert to `bitmap` then set into image view, It is not look good, It not get original image, using glide library for url image path set to image view, I attached screen shot of capture image from `camera`

[image]

Comment: Can you post Imageview xml code and glide code?

Comment: <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/postImage"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="195dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           />

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(banner) .resize(2400, 1450)
                        .centerCrop() .into(holder.bannerImag);

Answer (score 0):

Change Imageview code like this

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/postImage"
     android:layout_gravity="center" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Also, change Picasso code like this

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(banner)
  .into(holder.bannerImag);
```

Basically, you should not hardcode the height/width values. It will change the image clarity.

Comment: but i want banner size image, I used above u mention xml but image set in small size only, How to change banner size?

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting the thumbnail in your onAcitityResult. You need to get the original file path to load the image of good quality.